# Visual C++ not showing up after download on Windows 7 (tried everything!)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I wasn't sure how exactly to word this so here goes. I tried to download Visual C++ 2010 for a class I'm taking, and after starting the installer it said I already had a newer version, which I don't remember downloading but anywho..

So I went to uninstall it from the programs panel, and there were 2 Visual C++ 2010 programs and 2 Visual C++ 2008 programs, including the Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio tools for office runtime. **THATS WHEN THE CRAZINESS ENSUED!**

Now not only are they all gone, but I have tried downloading VC++ multiple times and uninstalled the same amount and when I search for the program all I come up with is the install program. Also, all my folders for software writing programs are empty on the start-up menu (Visual Studio 2010,Dev-C++,Netbeans, python,Java etc.).

Did I delete something I wasn't supposed to? I have a Visual studio 2010 folder that looks legit with what it contains (even a visual c++ 2010 Express-ENU) folder but both only contain the installer.exe program and uninstall temp.exe program. Any idea what the heck is going on? Sorry it's not a "sexy" problem but any help at all but I just want to learn and code some damn C++! Thanks to all!

Comment: "it said I already had a newer version"  Sounds like a message from the libraries installer, which is just a small part of the development tools.  Not unusual to have the Visual C++ libraries already installed by other software.

Comment: In any case, you probably would want the latest Visual Studio 2013 express, since lots of compiler bugs have gotten fixed.  Or community edition, which includes even more.  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx

Comment: If you are taking a class, you might be eligible to use https://www.dreamspark.com to download a complete full version.  Check with your school/IT department.

Comment: So how do I get the actual program? I've uninstalled/installed multiple times and each time i've installed the actual visual c++ was nowhere to be found, even after searching, all that was left when I typed in visual c++ to the searchbar was the setup program.

Comment: With an updated Windows 7, VS 2013 (and I would think the express version as well) works fine. I use it. The earliest versions were troublesome.

Comment: Also Visual Studio creates a restore point before a proper install. If it was recently you can restore to that to undo anything bad you might have done.

Comment: I have a laptop with windows 7 as well, and I am using visual studio express with no problems. Another version you might like to look at is the community version of visual studio which has a lot more utilities than the express version (almost like the pro version) but the licensing limits it to personal and learning uses, which is the case based on your post. Also, this might not be the case, but are you by any chance installing Visual C++ redistributable package instead of the actual Visual C++?

Comment: captain giraffe I would think that as well, and I looked for a restore point but found none, perhaps because the original download was halted when it said I had a new version?   triple_r yes I am using the redistributable package, that's the only one I could find on Microsoft's website that was 2010...Not a good idea?

Comment: The redistributable package is not Visual C++. It is just libraries that can be used by programs developed with Visual C++.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. After searching through program files, I've found the visual studio 2010, and in it there's a "microsoft visual c++ 2010 express-enu" folder with a lot of .dll files and otheres but the only executable programs are the setup.exe, DeleteTemp.exe, and vs_setup.MSI  I ran setup.exe and it downloaded all the files including .net and all that but still I can't find the damn program itself and it doesn't open automatically.

Comment: Looks like you are fiddling with the VS redistributable packages and not the IDE. You need to download and install Visual Studio.

Comment: Hmm ok, I'm installing visual studio community 2013 with update 4 so I'll see how that goes. If not screw it I'm just going to use NetBeans. Thanks for all the help everybody!